# coProcessFunction vs keyedCoProcessFunction on connected keyed streams

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In referring  to Flink code samples, I observed that when connecting two streams using the `connect` operator, both `coProcessFunction` and `keyedCoProcessFunction` are being extended almost interchangeably and identically when operating on keyed streams (overriding `processElement1`, `processElement2`, and `onTimer`), So when operating on keyed streams what is the difference between extending `CoProcessFunction` as compared to `keyedCoProcessFunction` to implementent the business logic of the keyed connected stream?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`KeyedCoProcessFunction` and `KeyedProcessFunction` were added somewhat recently. The difference compared to the non-keyed flavors is that the current key is available in the `Context` that gets passed to the various processElement and onTimer methods.

If you try to use keyed state or timers in a ProcessFunction or CoProcessFunction, it will work if you are actually in a keyed context, and will throw an exception if you are not.

Comment: The current docs state: "KeyedProcessFunction, as an extension of ProcessFunction, gives access to the key of timers in its onTimer(...) method".  So, assuming that one doesn't need to access the current key value like this `K key = ctx.getCurrentKey();`, it seem that they are mostly interchangeable. Am I right?

Comment: You should use a `KeyedProcessFunction` if you are using keyed state or timers. Otherwise it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks David! Still not 100% clear to me, though. The current docs say: "The ProcessFunction can be thought of as a FlatMapFunction with access to keyed state and timers", so, based on this statement, it seems that a normal (non-keyed) ProcessFunction can already work with keyed state and timers, as also claimed here: "If you want to access keyed state and timers you have to apply the ProcessFunction on a keyed stream: stream.keyBy(...).process(new MyProcessFunction());".

Comment: As the answer above these comments says, you can use keyed state and timers in a ProcessFunction, and it will work, so long as the function is actually being used in a keyed context. But there's no good reason to do that. It is supported for backwards compatibility reasons, but is otherwise just a way to write code that is unnecessarily opaque about what's being done. Which is why I said you _should_ use a KeyedProcessFunction rather than you _must_ use one.

Comment: Thanks a lot David, now it's 100% clear to me!